# Which techniques choose similar and dissimilar observations in a dataset?

Tags: r, pca, discriminant-analysis

I have a dataset of dutch municipalities (rows) and a lot of variables (cols, variables). Given one municipality or the average of some, with what technique can I find municipalities that resemble this municipality on the variables, and how can I find municipalities that differ as much as possible on these variables.

I know discriminant analysis, but as far as I know I must tell it beforehand the groups into which I want to discriminate. In my case I want a kind of metric which makes me choose the desired municipalities (something like eigenvalues in PCA to choose the factors). Anyhow, this will not tell me which municipalities *resemble* the chosen base set.

My knowledge of statistics is somewhat rusty, not having needed it for 30 years. My apologies if this is a nooby question. It will help me enormously if someone points me to some techniques. I might be able to find out the rest myself :-). I use R for the analysis.

Comment: You seem to be looking for unsupervised classification algorithms. I would suggest to begin with exploring hierarchical clustering (munis closer to business/tourist centers vs. industrial centers) example for cars dataset `plot(hclust(dist(mtcars)))`. You could also look at other schemes such as `kmeans` and additional examples from [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/cluster-analysis-in-r-unsupervised-machine-learning) and [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html)

Comment: Cluster analysis would be a good idea for your situation.  Whether you are best using the type known as hierarchical, or kmeans, or some other will partly depend on what sorts of variables you are working with.

Comment: @hNu, rolando2, thanks very much for the suggestion. I have looked briefly in cluster analysis and I am sure I have to do some studying. this will take some time I think :-). I hadn't thought of cluster analysis uptill now, so thanks very much and thanks for the links!